# error msg - is not a function when using prototype for an Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-services

I am building an Angular service for some re-usable code for an upload named 'UploadService' which gets called within a controller below - even though the service has been loaded in I always get the following error

```
`UploadService.upload is not a function at h.$scope.uploadImage...)`
```

My Upload Service (UploadService.js)

```
abcdServices.service('UploadService', function(ApiService, $http, $localStorage, $location, $timeout, $q, $rootScope, Upload) {

var UploadService = function() {
      this.upload_in_progress = false;
      this.attached_media = {
        photos: [],
        videos: []
      }
  };

  UploadService.prototype.upload = function(files) {
     console.log('get here');

  };

  return UploadService;

});
```

// My Controller where the service is called - note I have added this to the

```
    $scope.uploadImage = function(files, fileIndex, imageIndex) {
        console.log('existing upload image');
        console.log(files); // this shows an array in the console log as expected
        UploadService.prototype.upload(files);

    }
```

// The controller has the service loaded in at the top and I have included UserService.js file in the index.php

```
abcdControllers.controller('PostController', function( $http, $rootScope, UploadService) {
```

Comment: Just curious, Why do you need to use _prototype_ in Angular service?

Comment: @Satpal this was purely from the previous developer that worked on this (no other reason.. I presume using prototype is overkill)

Comment: No it's not an overkill, *prototype* is very much a javascript way to add instance members to a "Class". The thing is, you have to use the `UploadService.upload()` directly not through the *prototype* `UploadService.prototype.upload()` because `UploadService` is not a reference to the class, angularjs' injector gives you an instance of that class.

Answer (score 1):

The *prototype* is just a javascript way to add instance members to a "Class". The point is, you have to use the `UploadService.upload()` directly not through the *prototype* `UploadService.prototype.upload()` because `UploadService` is not a reference to the class, angularjs' injector gives you an instance of that class, when you declare a service `UploadService`, angularjs injects a singleton reference to `new UploadService()`.

Also, you are declaring the service class in the wrong way, your approach doesn't return the UploadService class for the injector, it only returns a function that returns the UploadService, which is never exposed. A better approach for that would be something like the code bellow:

```
abcdServices.service('UploadService', function UploadService(ApiService, $http, $localStorage, $location, $timeout, $q, $rootScope, Upload) {    
    this.upload_in_progress = false;
    this.attached_media = {
        photos: [],
        videos: []
    };

    this.upload = function(files) {
        console.log('get here');    
    };    
});
```

Or you can simply change it to a factory provider and return a new instance of your "Class":

```
abcdServices.factory('UploadService', function(ApiService, $http, $localStorage, $location, $timeout, $q, $rootScope, Upload) {    
  var UploadService = function() {
      this.upload_in_progress = false;
      this.attached_media = {
        photos: [],
        videos: []
      };
  };

  UploadService.prototype.upload = function(files) {
     console.log('get here');    
  };

  return new UploadService();    
});
```

Comment: I have tried the second method and still have some issues in related to this question in regards to passing data to the class properties for some reason with cordova file transfer plugin

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223486/angular-service-factory-class-property-not-updating-inside-the-cordova-file-tr

Comment: @Zabs this question has nothing to do with your new issues, as far as I can see you don't know much of javascript particularities, your new problem is related to javascript scope definition, Unlike other OOP compliant languages like java and c#, javascript is prototypal, when you use `this` inside a function, you are referring to the function's scope not the parent scope like java does with classes, that is, `this.media_response` inside cordova's callback, refer to the callback's `this` not the service's `this`.