# Angular service/factory - class property not updating inside the cordova file transfer

Tags: angularjs, angular, cordova, angular-services, angular-factory

I have Angular service that does an Cordova File Transfer upload within a mobile app - it uploads a file to media server and returns an object. I am trying to pass this object to the `media_response` property but i'm having no luck - what I am doing wrong?

Please note - I have tried using a `service` and `factory` and still seem to get no joy - anything within the `$cordovaFileTransfer upload` block isn't passed to the class properties for some bizarre reason.

I am expecting to see `media_response` with the same output as the data variable which is an object returned from the media server but it says `no response`

Any idea why I'm not getting the expected response?

**// Expected response**

`UploadService.media_response in the controller should be an object to match the console.log(data)`

**// Actual response**

`UploadService.media_response is the string 'no response'`

**// Upload Service**

```
abcdServices.service('UploadService', function($http, $localStorage, $location, $q, $rootScope, $cordovaFileTransfer) {

var UploadService = function() {
    this.upload_in_progress = false;
    this.progress = 0;
    this.media_response = '';
};

UploadService.prototype.cordovaFileUpload = function (filename, url, targetPath) {
    this.upload_in_progress = true;
    this.media_response = 'no response';

    var options = {
        id: new Date() . getTime()  + filename,
        fileKey: "file",
        fileName: filename,
        chunkedMode: false,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        params : {'fileName': filename}
    };

    $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(url, targetPath, options).then(
        function(result) {
            // Success!
            var data = JSON.parse(result.response);
            console.log('file uploaded - response:', data); // ALWAYS A OBJECT
            this.media_response = 'fake response2';
            UploadService.media_response = 'fake response3';

            if (angular.isDefined(data.id)) {
                angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                    // image[key] = value;
                });
                // $scope.post.linkThumbnail = false;
                // $scope.post.video = '';
            } else if (angular.isDefined(data.message)) {
                // $scope.uploadError = data.message;

            } else {

            }
        }, function(err) {

        }, function (progress) {
            // constant progress updates
            this.progress = parseInt(100 * progress.loaded / progress.total) + '%';
        }
    );

};

return new UploadService();});
```

**// controller**

```
UploadService.cordovaFileUpload(filename, url, targetPath, options);
console.log(UploadService); // to view in js console
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `this.` variables are scoped to the nearest function block, not the service/factory.

Create your variables in the root of your service/factory with either `var` or `let`.

---

```
abcdServices.service('UploadService', function($http, $localStorage, $location, $q, $rootScope, $cordovaFileTransfer) {

    let upload_in_progress = false;
    let progress = 0;
    let media_response = '';

    var UploadService = function() {
        upload_in_progress = false;
        progress = 0;
        media_response = '';
    };

    UploadService.prototype.cordovaFileUpload = function (filename, url, targetPath) {
        upload_in_progress = true;
        media_response = 'no response';

        // Rest of your code
    };

return new UploadService();});
```

---

If you really need/want to use `this`, use the new function arrow notation, which does not create a new `this`-scope in the function block.

```
abcdServices.service('UploadService', function(...) {

    this.upload_in_progress = 'test';
    this.progress = 0;
    this.media_response = '';

    someFunction = (param1, param2, ..) => {
        console.log(this.upload_in_progress) // 'test'
    }

});
```